# How to apply changes to a dynamic form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a form that is generated by user's choice

this is the code :

```
<select id="skillcat" name="skillcat[]" class="form-control" onChange="getSkillDescription(this.value)">
<option value ="">SELECT SKILL CATEGORY</option>
<?php 
     foreach($results as $displayCategory) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $displayCategory["SkillCatID"]; ?>"><?php echo $displayCategory["SkillCatName"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<i class="arrow"></i>

<select id="skilldes" name="skilldes[]" class="form-control"></select>
<i class="arrow"></i>
```

so when i choosed a value for the first option,it will change the value for the second option.

this is the javascript for getSkillDescription()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSkillDescription(val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "get_skilldescription.php",
data:'skill_id='+val,
success: function(data){
$("#skilldes").html(data);
}});}
</script>
```

The script will head to get_skilldescription.php. below is the code:

```
<?php
include("include/dbconn.php");
session_start();
     $kp = $_SESSION["id"];
function runQuery($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }       
    if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
}

if(!empty($_POST["skill_id"])) {

$skill=$_POST["skill_id"];

switch($skill)
{
 case 1: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 1";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 2: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 2";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 3: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 3";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 4: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 4";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 5: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 5";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 6: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 6";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 7: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 7";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 8: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 8";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 9: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 9";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 10: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 10";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 11: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 11";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 12: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 12";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 13: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 13";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 14: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 14";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 15: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 15";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 16: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 16";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 17: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 17";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;
    case 18: $query ="SELECT * FROM skill WHERE skillCatID = 18";
            $results = runQuery($query); break;


}
?>
<option value="">Select Skill</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $displayskill) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $displayskill["SkillID"]; ?>"><?php echo $displayskill["SkillDescription"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Now the problem is,when I add a new form, it will create another two option. But when i changed the newly created form's first option, it will change the values of option of the first form, not the newly created form. I hope you guys can help me to fix this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a new form where the elements have the same ids as the first form.

Ids are unique, make sure each form has fields with unique ids.

Also, you are calling again `getSkillDescription` which sets explicitly the first select option `$("#skilldes")` so you need to make this function generic where you pass the id of the select you will be populating.

```
function getSkillDescription(val, selectID) {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "get_skilldescription.php",
       data:'skill_id='+val,
       success: function(data){
          $("#" + selectID).html(data);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            if(rowCount < 20){  // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
                var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
                var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
                for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
                    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                } }else{
                 alert("Maximum is 20.");}};

Comment: You do not have to clone the content of row 1 to create a new row, you can set the newcell innerHTML explicitly with the new content where you append to each select id an index to differentiate it and call the `getSkillDescription` in the same manner. Besides, why do you need too much forms in your page, a single form can be sufficient and can contain all your fields.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same ID #skilldes to populate your second form with the response from your Ajax call. Make sure to use unique ID for each.